# PHP MYSQL <?php echo $row[$variable]; ?>

Tags: php, mysql, variables, echo

I have the following code that does what I want it to do, but the ones with the backslashes `<?php echo $row[\'t_id\']; ?>`, the `<?php echo $row[\'t_type\']; ?>` and the `<?php echo ucfirst$row[\'t_fn\']).\'&nbsp;\'.ucfirst($row[\'t_ln\']); ?>` do not output their respective variable.

Instead, their output is literal like

```
view_t_profile.php?tutor_id=<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>&t_type=<?php echo $row['t_type']; ?>
```

The `<?php echo ucfirst$row['t_fn']).'&nbsp;'.ucfirst($row['t_ln']); ?>` doesn't show up on the web page like the previous code, but its in the code italicized and in red text. I'm not a programmer/coder, so if someone can correct my code, I sure would appreciate it. Usually, I can figure it out, but on this one, I cannot.

```
<?php

if($row['t_type'] == 1)

{

echo '<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF"><a href="view_t_profile.php?t_id=<?php echo $row[\'t_id\']; ?>&t_type=<?php echo $row[\'t_type\']; ?>" class="cls" target="_blank"><br />View Profile</a></font></strong></center>';
echo '<center><strong>Main Contact</strong></center>';
echo '<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF"><?php echo ucfirst$row[\'t_fn\']).\'&nbsp;\'.ucfirst($row[\'t_ln\']); ?></font></strong></center>';

}

if($row['t_type'] == 0)

{

echo '<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF"><a href="view_t_profile.php?t_id=<?php echo $row[\'t_id\']; ?>&t_type=<?php echo $row[\'t_type\']; ?>" class="cls" target="_blank"><br />View Profile</a></font></strong></center>';
echo '<center><strong>Main Sponsor</strong></center>';
echo '<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF"><?php echo ucfirst$row[\'t_fn\']).\'&nbsp;\'.ucfirst($row[\'t_ln\']); ?></font></strong></center>';

}

?>
```

Comment: Remove all of the backslashes and open and close the echo statement with true quotes `"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `<?php echo ... ?>` when you're already in PHP mode and echoing something. Just concatenate the variable.

```
echo '<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF">' . ucfirst($row['t_fn']) . '&nbsp;' . ucfirst($row['t_ln']) . '</font></strong></center>';
```

`<?php echo ... ?>` is used when you're just outputting HTML directly, and you want to insert a bit of PHP. For instance, like this:

```
if($row['t_type'] == 1)
{ ?>
<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF"><a href="view_t_profile.php?t_id=<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>&t_type=<?php echo $row['t_type']; ?>" class="cls" target="_blank"><br />View Profile</a></font></strong></center>
<center><strong>Main Contact</strong></center>
<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF"><?php echo ucfirst$row['t_fn']).'&nbsp;'.ucfirst($row['t_ln']); ?></font></strong></center>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I've update the answer to show the alternate form, where you print everything in HTML mode rather than with `echo` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

if($row['t_type'] == 1)

{

echo '<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF"><a href="view_t_profile.php?t_id='.$row['t_id'].'&t_type='.$row['t_type'].'" class="cls" target="_blank"><br />View Profile</a></font></strong></center>';
echo '<center><strong>Main Contact</strong></center>';
echo '<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF">'.ucfirst$row['t_fn']).' '.ucfirst($row['t_ln']).'</font></strong></center>';

}

if($row['t_type'] == 0)

{

echo '<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF"><a href="view_t_profile.php?t_id='.$row['t_id'].'&t_type='.$row[\'t_type\'].'" class="cls" target="_blank"><br />View Profile</a></font></strong></center>';
echo '<center><strong>Main Sponsor</strong></center>';
echo '<center><strong><font color="#3BB9FF">'.ucfirst$row['t_fn']).' '.ucfirst($row['t_ln']).'</font></strong></center>';

}

?>
```

When you open `<?php` once, you can't use this tags again, before you close with `?>` tag.

Comment: Thank you user3577136 for your help. Your code helped too except for the missing ( before the $row, but I got the idea from the next code in what to do to make it work.