# create html table with variable rows using php inside phpmailer

Tags: php, html

So I am trying to email a message to someone using phpmailer. When this is email it needs that can have a variable number of rows. I found some code here that pointed me in the right direction but a couple things are happening when I put this code into the message.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>SKU Number</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($stuff as $trow) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $trow->$name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trow->$sku; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trow->$price; ?></td>
    </tr> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

First the foreach loop is closing at the end of the first row, at least that is what I assume since I have no other rows after the first one. Second when this sends the email I get the email but the semicolon, question mark, and closing bracket are all as in each cell with their data. The data I get for the first row is accurate however. Just get nothing past it. Am I missing something with this code? Should I post all my code to help narrow it down? I posted my phpmailer code. Is it perhaps that I'm trying to call php twice? Although I would think that it wouldn't matter since the $message contents are an html email sent to the email address.

```
to_name="$firstname $lastname";
$to="to@email.address";
$subject="Your store order for: $date";
$headers="MIME-VERSION1.0\r\n";
$headers .="Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message="Dear $custfirstname $custlastname, Thank you for choosing this store for your purchase. You purchsed the following items on $date at store $store.<br>";

$message .="<table border=\"1\">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>SKU Number</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($stuff as $trow) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $trow->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trow->sku; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trow->price; ?></td>
    </tr> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>";


$message .="Please fill out these surveys below to tell us how your         experience was with our company.";

$from_name="from name";
$from = "from@email.address";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host ="mailhost";
$mail->Port =25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->Username="mailboxsendingmessage";
$mail->Password="passwordforsendingmailbox";
$mail->FromName=$from_name;
$mail->From=$from; 
$mail->AddAddress($to, $to_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $message; 

$result = $mail->Send();
echo $result ? 'Sent' : 'Error';
$mailsend = NULL;
$mailsend = $result;

echo "$mailsend";
```

EDIT: added my php mailer code.

Comment: What is the output of `<?php var_dump($stuff); ?>` ? This will tell you if the $stuff variable is structured correctly and has all of the rows that you want to print. Other than that, the syntax looks correct to me.

Comment: I suspect you have this code inside an `echo` statement, not inside a block of HTML code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831134/php-mysql-php-echo-rowvariable/32831570#32831570

Comment: If you hardcode `$stuff` and then run this loop, what does it print out?  i.e. make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I suspect that your issue lies outside this particular code block, but we'll never know if you don't test it.

Comment: If you pass that code block to a browser as HTML, you get `Item Name  SKU Number  Price` and
`$name; ?>  $sku; ?>  $price; ?>`  on separate lines, does look like what you are getting?  Can you provide the relevant snippet of HTML that this code is producing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html like this

```
    $message .='<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>SKU Number</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>';

    <?php foreach($stuff as $trow) { ?>

    $message .='<tr>
    <td>'.$trow->name.'</td>
    <td>'.$trow->sku.'</td>
    <td>'.$trow->price.'</td>
    </tr>'; 
    <?php } ?>
$message .='</tbody>
</table>';
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had to make changes to make sure my data showed due to errors on my part but otherwise this was perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found confusing to loop that way, I always prefer the [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).
This is what I normally do:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>SKU Number</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

foreach($stuff as $trow){
echo <<< LOL
<tr> 
<td>{$trow->$name}</td>
<td>{$trow->$sku}</td>
<td>{$trow->$price}</td>
</tr> 
LOL;
}

?>
</tbody>
```

---

You'll end-up will less code and consequently less errors.

Comment: Would this till work within the contents of an html message from phpmailer? Going to try it and see how it does.

Comment: I've used  `heredoc` with `PHPMailer` previously and it works, also, make sure you set the correct mime type to handle html on your email.

Comment: Unfortunately, `heredoc` did not work. The table now returns as empty with << showing up underneath price and then the cell will contain ROW;}?>

Comment: I'm sre this is something I'm struggling with on formatting but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

With the additional code the problem becomes clear.

You are inserting PHP statements into a string, which is then being sent in the email.  If you view the source of that email message, you will likely see the PHP code that was not executed.

You cannot interpolate a foreach loop inside of a string.  Instead, you will need to incrementally build your string using the loop, like

```
$message .="<table border=\"1\">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>SKU Number</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";

foreach($stuff as $trow) :
    $message .= "<tr>
    <td>".$trow->name."</td>
    <td>".$trow->sku."</td>
    <td>".$trow->price."</td>
    </tr>";
endforeach;
$message .= "</tbody>
</table>";
```